# First moments of Geometric Brownian Motion-like process with non-normal shocks

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus, finance, exponential-distribution

First consider a standard GBM process of the form,

$$\frac{dS_t}{S_t} =  \mu \, dt+ \sigma \, dW_t$$

but instead of the normal $W_t \sim N(0,1)$ , instead we have that, $$W_t \sim \operatorname{EMG}^-(0,1,\lambda)$$

where $\operatorname{EMG}^-$ is the Exponentially Modified Gaussian$^{[1]}$ distribution  corresponding to the random variable $W=X-Y$, where $X\sim N(\cdot)$ and $Y \sim \operatorname{EXP}(\lambda)$. Basically what this distribution gives is a standard normal variable with a slight left skew due to the subtraction of the exponential.

Now that we have the problem set up, two things jump out:

1. $W_t$ is not a Wiener process (because it does not satisfy having Gaussian increments) so this is not a GBM.
2. Because $\frac{dS_t}{S_t}$ is not a GBM we cannot do ito calculus with it (at least as far as I understand it).

If this was a standard GBM you could do the standard thing of saying, look $\frac{dS_t}{S_t}=\ln(S_t)=f(S_t)$ and then compute the ito derivative of $f(S_t)$ as $$d(f(S_t))=\frac{\partial f}{\partial S}\, dS_t+\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial S^2} \,dS_t^2$$

So at long last my question is, how do you handle a GBM-like process when the shocks are not iid standard normal? How do you solve for this process $S_t$ and find the first moments of it?

[1]: For more information on the $\operatorname{EMG}^+$ distribution, see here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentially_modified_Gaussian_distribution

EDIT: Doing some more reading since I have posted this leads me to believe that $W_t$ is a semi-martingale and there are methods of dealing with semi-martingales in Ito calculus. A would expect a solution would probably start there. I am currently trying that way to tackle it myself but if anyone else comes up with an answer in the meantime it would be very welcome.

Comment: By $\operatorname{EXP}(\lambda),$ do you mean exponential with rate $\lambda,$ or exponential with expectation $\lambda\text{?} \qquad$

Comment: An exponential with rate $\lambda$

Comment: May I ask where this problem comes from? Is it that you want to find a process with that distribution? Also, I think the distribution of $W_t$ should depend on $t$. (For starters, $W_t\sim N(0,t)$.)

Comment: $W_t$ is not distributed like $N(0,1)$, but like $N(0,t)$.